# How to fork self in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I want to fork a new process in the very begin of my nodejs app.js, then in main process, a http server will be created, and in new process i will run a `while true` loop to do some jobs.

I have read `child_process.fork(modulePath,..)`, it requires a `modulePath`, in my case I only need to fork a process like `fork()` in `C`

something like this:

```
// very begin of the server.js
fork(function(new_process) {
  // child process
  while(true) {
    //do sth
  }
});
// main process
// balabala
server.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered, "fork" is poorly named: it's actually a fork/exec.

You might want to consider either of these alternatives:

- [Threads A-GoGo](https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo/blob/master/README.md)
- [Webworker Threads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads)

You might also consider Node.js clustering:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-concurrency

Finally, this article might be of interest:

- http://neilk.net/blog/2013/04/30/why-you-should-use-nodejs-for-CPU-bound-tasks/